# SEO url rewrite in ASP.CORE 2.0

Tags: url-rewriting, routes, seo, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this scenario:
I have an url like this:

> https://localhost/Cars/Model?modelId=dc95cb43-f249-492a-8dcc-33d5b540895c

I want to rewrite it to became something like this:

> https://localhost/Cars/Model/audi-a4

Where audi-a4 is an unique description in database, description corelated with

`modelId=dc95cb43-f249-492a-8dcc-33d5b540895c`

I have searched a little bit on the internet but I couldn't find something related to this. I have found different ways of rewriting but not what I want to do.

Does anyone have any ideea how this could be solved ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your request correctly you would like your user to type

```
https: // localhost / Cars / Model / audi-a4
```

and have it rewritten as:

```
https: // localhost / Cars / Model? modelId = dc95cb43-f249-492a-8dcc-33d5b540895c
```

If that's what you want to do then you can define a rewrite rule that matches the exact template "Model/audi-a4"
and rewrite the url by replacing *"Model/audi-a4"* by *"modelId=dc95cb43-f249-492a-8dcc-33d5b540895c"*

Otherwise why not manage by code? 
So that your modelId parameter can be the string modelId=dc95cb43-f249-492a-8dcc-33d5b540895c or the string audi-a4?

which would amount to:

```
https: // localhost / Cars / Model? modelId = audi-a4
```